# Gravitational potential inside a solid sphere

Tags: newtonian-gravity

To calculate the gravitational potential at any point inside a solid sphere, why do we need to separately integrate gravitational field from infinity to radius and then from radius to the point?

Why can't we do it like for a point outside or on the surface where we just need to integrate from infinity to the point because all the stacked hollow shells act from their centers.

Comment: The electric field is different in both regions, so you need to separate them.

Comment: Because once you're inside the sphere there are less of these stacked shells, and as you go deeper there are progressively less.

In principle is just one integration, that splits because the function being integrated is piece-wise defined, where the surface is the limit between the two pieces.

Comment: @jinawee: electric field?

Comment: @KyleKanos I'm having an electromagnetism test next week... Still, the concept is the same.

Comment: @jinawee: Oh I know the concept is the same, I was just wondering how you turned $G$ into $E$. But the test makes sense; good luck on it!